# FTP client unable to LIST server contents due to local firewall

Tags: command-line, firewall, ftp

TL;DR -

1. Local Firewall On: FTP connects successfully, LIST / LS / DIR return Error 425 Could not open data connection to port [large port number]: Connection timed out.
2. Local Firewall Off: FTP connects successfully, LIST / LS / DIR also succeed.

Before we get on to FTP:Passive vs. FTP:Active - it's not that. Both Passive and Active essentially do the same thing.

The connection goes like this:

```
<Standard beginning connection bumf to remote Pure-FTP server>
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> dir
200 PORT command successful
425 Could not open data connection to port 46811: Connection timed out
ftp> quit
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout.
```

When not on Windows, I come from the Red Hat / Fedora / CentOS camp, but I'm trying Zorin on a salvaged Lenovo R61. And I've never had so many issues trying to do something "simple". Have I overlooked something basic?

**Maybe? Have you allowed it through the firewall?**

Right, of course. I tried that, but couldn't get it to work.

As above, I've tried FTPing with the local machine's software firewall disabled (via GUI), and that allows the connection. I've tried adding a large swathe of ephemeral ports in as allowing - that didn't work either. And I've tried adding "FTP" as a service into the GUI firewall->Add, and I tried adding FTP via UFW too.

**Have you tried Googling it?**

Yes, I've tried that too. It's flooded with so much *FTP server* info/config/issues that I couldn't find anything much specifically for this issue that wasn't actually a Passive FTP solution. And as I said, in this case, PASS doesn't make any difference, and Active works when local firewall is off.

Also, I happen to have wireshark on this machine, and I watched the connections during a 'failure', the output of wireshark showed no activity.

**Question:**
How does one successfully allow FTP through the local firewall of a workstation?

---

**Edit**

So I tried this on my Win10 machine using WinSCP, and *at first* experienced the same problem. So I tried it via the Windows command line, and the firewall permission box popped up, which then allowed me to successfully LIST on FTP via CLI. (... and upon retrying the WinSCP, that got the auth box too, and then worked as expected.)

I've added this to show that: same network, same destination server, same pathways etc work when on a different machine.

Comment: What firewalls and/or NAT routers are on both the client and server ends of the connection? Short summary: active FTP (mostly) works through server-side firewalls, and passive FTP (mostly) works through client-side firewalls. If you have firewalls on both ends, things get really messy. Also: FTP is an ancient protocol, designed before we really knew how such things should work. It has a number of problems, and this is just one of them. If possible, use a more modern protocol.

Comment: Yes, it's old. However, it's in use. In this case, what baffles me is that from a Windows 10 machine, I can FTP, FTP + Encryption (explicit?) (note the distinction between that, and SFTP or FTPS) - but from this Zorin / Ubuntu machine I can't. -> I am going to edit the question to ensure everyone realises I'm talking about the actual software firewall on the machine in question.

Comment: To actually answer your question @GordonDavisson, in order of appearance  Laptop, Wireless, DSL, {Interwebs}, Firewall/Router, cPanel server.